# Problema con EditText dentro de RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, edittext

espero poder hacer que me entiendan, tengo un RecyclerView que contiene a varios EditText pero cuando este pasa al ultimo elemento mostrado en pantalla ya no me muestra o sea 7, a partir del ocho, se puede escribir en el EditText pero no se muestra en pantalla simplemente se queda abajo y no se reajusta, en el vídeo parece como si yo bajara manualmente hacia los elementos no visibles pero yo no hago esto, no se como es que aparece con el grabador de pantalla que usé.

[Este es el vídeo capturado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iCRR8Ougn0)

El codigo de mi RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerDatos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

El CardView del adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/posicionDato"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="N"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/xDato"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/yDato"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/eliminarDato"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:tint="@color/primary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_eliminar_dato"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Agradecería su ayuda, está volviendome loco.

Comment: el video no se ve nada, intenta pone alguna foto o algo de lo que sucede porque no me queda muy claro